# Are all Hermitian matrices beyond complex diagonalizable?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization, quaternions, hermitian-matrices

I know this has been asked here before with respect to complex numbers but I am curious about the case of Hermitian matrices of quaternions, octonions or in fact anything which can be conjugated? Basically does the spectral theorem hold for ALL conjugable mathematical objects?

Comment: Quaternions and octonions are not fields, as such I don't see how to use the spectral theorem. On the other hand they admit a representation in terms of matrices and then you can go back and use the standard spectral theorem.

Comment: Even the eigenvalue problem over quaternions is difficult to deal with.  See [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math-ph/0211063.pdf) for instance

Comment: See also theorem 3.3 of [this paper](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82151498.pdf)

Comment: Thanks, this turns out to be more interesting than I had thought :)